# Unable to add device in Apple Developer Program

Tags: ios, ios-provisioning, iphone-developer-program

I am unable to add a new device in the Certificates, Identifiers, and Profiles section of the Apple Developer portal.

I have two developer accounts, one personal account and one account for a company. The account for the company, I am set as a 'member' for the team. This is the account that I am unable to add a new device for. (I am also not able to download the Distribution certificate, which I believe is a related issue that I need resolved too).

I have researched the other similar questions on SO, but neither of them applied to my scenario.

Here is a picture showing the `+` button disabled (greyed out)

[image]

Comment: How many devices you've added?

Comment: @ronan Me personally, none. I just got added to the company today as a member. Total devices added to the team is only 17

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From Apple documentation:

> Team members can’t register devices and create development
>   provisioning profiles using their developer account.

Ask from someone who has Team admin or Team agent privileges to add you.

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering about that because the sentence before that reads `A team member can create their development certificate, register a device connected to their Mac, and create a team provisioning profile using Xcode.` So to me it kind of sounded like they contradicted each other.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. Team Members are unable to add a new device via the Developer Portal. However, they are allowed to add a new device to the provisioning file via XCode. I was working with Xamarin and didn't know that I needed to go back to XCode in order to add a new device to the provisioning file.

If you're working in Xamarin and experience this problem, you need to create a 'dummy app' in XCode with the same info as your Xamarin app. Then select your team and it should generate the correct provisioning file for you. After that, build and run your app on your device, then a pop up window should display telling you that the device is not in the provisioning file, then asks if you would like to add it. A simple click of 'Yes' will automatically add the device to the provisioning file which is then reflected on the Developer Account.

Hope that helps someone else! I spent many hours trying to figure this out.